# How to set the formula field as static?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a two parameters say:

```
@fromcode,@tocode
```

I need to create two formula field which should display the Description of (`@fromcode`,`@tocode`) parameter respectively and it should remain static throughout the report.Am using crystal report 2008.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you created the formula fields?

Comment: @fromcode&'-'&Description  but the description keeps changing..i want to show only description corresponding to the @fromcode say, code =001 and desc is Ind but for me it keeps changing

Comment: what is the static description you need to show.... if the description need not to be changed then just hard code because you are using database field which will change as the data is changing... also where did you put the formula in report?

Comment: select code&'-'&Desc from table where code = '@fromcode'

how to do this in crystal report formula. i cannot hardcode it since it has millions of records whatever user input in fromcode  i want to display the code along with description and i want to display the formula field in the report header.

Comment: Is problem solved?

Comment: no its not done

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Formula and fix the From Code and To Code in it like the following example:

```
'From: ' + {?FromCode} + '- To: ' + {?ToCode}
```

In this way it will show the entered parameters in each time.